# IsolatedContext vs. AndroidTestCase.getContext()

Tags: android, testing, android-context

I'm writing some tests to test my sqllite database code. Can someone here explain if there would be a difference writing those tests using the context I get from [`AndroidTestCase.getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#getContext()) or using an [`IsolatedContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/IsolatedContext.html).

Comment: You should consider marking the inlined answer as correct, instead of the link, per stackoverflow rules about not just providing links (which may go down).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3a7bbc78258a194a?tvc=2

Answer (score 9):

For those that don't want to follow the link to the Google Group, here is the answer given there:

> AndroidTestCase.getContext() returns a normal Context object. It's the
>   Context of the test case, not the component under test.
>
> IsolatedContext returns a "mock" Context. I put "mock" in quotes 
>   because its not a mock in the normal sense of that term (for testing).
>   Instead, it's a template Context that you have to set up yourself. It 
>   "isolates" you from the running Android system, so that your Context 
>   or your test doesn't accidentally get outside of the test fixture. For
>   example, an IsolatedContext won't accidentally hit a production 
>   database (unless you set it up to do that!) Note, however, that some 
>   of the methods in an IsolatedContext may throw exceptions. 
>   IsolatedContext is documented in the Developer Guide under Framework 
>   Topics > Testing, both in Testing Fundamentals and in Content Provider
>   Testing.

[Here is the Android docs on IsolatedContext.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/IsolatedContext.html)

[And here is the relevant section of the Testing Fundamentals document.](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#ContextMocks)

Answer (score 2):

I had the simple problem: I need to test my DAO class without touching the real database. So I found the `IsolatedContext` from docs. But finally I found the other context in the same docs: `RenamingDelegatingContext` might be more easier to use. Here is my test case:

```
public class AddictionDAOTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setContext(new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_"));
    }

    public void testReadAllAddictions() throws Exception {
        ImQuitDAO imQuitDAO = new ImQuitDAO(getContext());
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this example finally helped me figure out how to do this. I must have googled and searched through the android documentation a few hours and never found an example as simple and useful as yours.